# Vue.js data changed but view not

Tags: vue.js

I defined an object in data as

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      labelPosition: 'right',
      isText: false,
      isDate: false,
      isExam: false,
      isFile: false,
      isWrite: false,
      stepLists: [],
      flowId: '',
      txtName: '',
      form: {
        textName: '',
        textPosition: '',
      }
```

the html like this : 
when I change  the form.textName ,I found it doesn't work

```
this.$set(this.form, 'textName', temp.name) //not work
 this.form={textName:'abc'}
 this.form = Object.assign({}, this.form)

 //not work

  this.$set(this.form,'textName', '---------------------') work well.
```

Comment: What is the object temp? Which is is value?

Comment: What is `temp` object?

Comment: did you tried to console.log() your temp.name ? what inside of it ? another thing you can set your data as : this.form.textName = 'your text here';

Comment: text(params) {
      if (!params) {
          return
      }
      var textFile = {
          textName: params.name,
          textPosition: params.position,
          textMust: params.isMust,
          textTitle: params.isTitle
      }
     var temp = params

Comment: before use temp I assign to the temp an object,equal the form